# Meteor: How latency compensation works between client and server

Tags: javascript, meteor

Latency compensation:

When the client wants to know something it asks first the local data cache on the browser, and it renders the page as per the result, if the server has different answer it patches the client's cache, consequently, the automatic page rendering

My Question:

1- How does the server know that there is a change on the client that need to be omitted or updated?

2- Does this happen by pulling the server for changes or the server pushes the changes back?

3- In operations like search operation, what if the customer doesn't have the result (say a user only has his own profile data but not other users), does the client request propagates to the server automatically, or I have to directly ask that from the server through a server method?

Comment: The answers are: It depends on what exactly you are doing. Are you working with Collections, pub/sub, methods? Please add some more explanations or sample code to explain your exact use-case. Explaining how latency compensation operates in all the cases is way too long for an SO answer.

Comment: Can you please answer the question in both cases: pub/sub and methods. I'm interested to know how things go under the scenes in both cases

Comment: 1.2. oplog tailing with fallback to pooling if not available 3. it will search the client side only, you have to handle it via method to search it on the server

Comment: Mmh... That would get fairly lengthy. Explaining how pub/sub latency compensation works requires explaining quickly the concepts of Mongo cursors and minimongo, but Meteor Methods require a more lengthy explanation of the way client stubs work. If there is no duplicate question available I would suggest asking two separate questions. I am going to search for good duplicate targets now...

Comment: @MarkUretsky, what if the method is shared between the client and server, will it search first on the client and if it returns nothing it will search on server? How does it go?

Comment: The version that is on the client will be run as a "simulation", and the same method will be called on the server as well. The results and side effects are sent to the client and, if needed, the optimistic UI changes are patched.

Comment: @MasterAM, this means we call 2 methods by just calling that stub, the client one first then the server, right? Also, is it the same when we share the same method for client and server (buy just defining Meteor.methods out side client and server folders)?

Comment: Yes. If a method is defined on the client, it is run as a stub. It makes no difference if it is defined in a shared file or in separate files. The method is also called on the server using DDP.

Comment: @MasterAM, does the same thing happen if the code inside the stub is different than the code on server? Do we still have calls to the stub and server implicitly?

Comment: Makes no difference how it is defined. The server version is always called. The stub is called if it exists, event if it different from the server version. A stub is handled differently (e.g, method calls from within a stub are not processed). I consider the DDP remote method call as the primary action and the stub on the client as secondary.

Comment: @MasterAM, Many thanks!

Comment: For collections it is a bit different. The client normally subscribes to the subset of a collection. Only that subset is pushed to the client. For instance, only your own profile from the set of all available profiles. If you now search on the client for profiles, you would always find only one even though there are many more on the server. It is very much possible to subscribe to a different subset of profiles so that the server will push more documents from the collection to the client. Changes in documents in the subset that the client is subscribed to are always synced to/from the server.